# Different Links For Iframe jQuery Modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, modal-dialog

i have some jquery code to show iframe in modal window.

this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#modalDiv").dialog({
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                height: '800',
                width: '800',
                draggable: false,
                resizeable: false,   
                title: 'IFrame Modal Dialog'
            });
            $('#goToMyPage').click(
                function() {
                    url = '/addnews.html';
                    $("#modalDiv").dialog("open");
                    $("#modalIFrame").attr('src',url);
                    return false;
            });                 
      });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a id="goToMyPage" href="#">Go to My Page</a>
<div id="modalDiv">
<iframe id="modalIFrame" width="100%" height="100%" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="auto" title="Dialog Title"></iframe>
</div>
```

i just can use for 1 link. this link:

```
url = '/addnews.html';
```

HTML:

```
<a id="goToMyPage" href="#">Go to My Page</a>
```

how i can use this code for 4-5 links?

Comment: iFrames, welcome to 1998... ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can send url within addition params in a tag

```
<a id="goToMyPage" href="#" data-url="some-url" >Go to My Page</a>
```

and use it in your event

```
$('.goToMyPage').click(
            function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                url = $(this).attr('data-url');
                $("#modalDiv").dialog("open");
                $("#modalIFrame").attr('src',url);
                return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your js to trigger on class instead of ID, and modify links to use href
e.preventDefault() tells disables link from opening normally

```
       $('.goToMyPage').click(
            function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                url = $(this).prop('href');
                $("#modalDiv").dialog("open");
                $("#modalIFrame").attr('src',url);
                return false;
        });
```

then make your links look like this

```
<a class="goToMyPage" href="addnews.html">Go to My Page</a>
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific, what it does or where it hangs up? i wrote that on the fly so there might be some typos im totally willing to fix

Comment: sorry but im not professional with jquery! could u please fix this code for me? :(

Comment: as i thought, $.prop('href') returns value already. Fixed code above, working on my end now as far as i can test. I used straight $("#modal").load(url) tho, as i don't like iframes.

Comment: Not working for me! i need to use iframe, i know its not good but i dont have any choice...

Comment: get your hands dirty, because i can't help if all you say is 'not working for me'. provide some input